# Run SQL Unit Test in TFS Build Pipeline

Tags: sql, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a SQL Unit test project (.sqlproj) as part of my solution. What do I do to run my tests in my build pipeline? If a test fails I would like the build to break?

Visual Studio Test Assemblies is for C# Unit Tests and not SQL

Comment: How is your build pipeline implemented, what tools and build server?

Comment: I actually figured out what I was doing wrong. The SQL project does not produce a DLL so you don't use that project in the Test Assemblies task in TFS